# How to SET DATEFIRST equal to Wednesday in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

In my DimDate table , Week Day start with "Wednesday" and Ends with " Tuesday" , Now i need to generate week numbers accordingly, To achieve that i need to set my date first to Wednesday ? 
Is there any other possibilities to achieve the below requirement

Please find the below Sample data I need to populate.

[image]

As per 2017-01-01 day starts with Sunday which is default datefirst , but in my case i need to give daynumber for that is 2017-01-01 daynumber= 4 and week =1, 2017-01-02 daynumber =5, 2017-01-01 daynumber= 6 and week =1 
next Wednesday 01-04-2017 is daynumebr = 0 and week = 2  and so on ......

Answer (score 0):

This will set your daynumber as 0 for Wednesday and ending with 6 for Tuesday:

```
case when date_part(dw,source_date)-3<0 
     then date_part(dw,source_date)+4 
     else date_part(dw,source_date)-3 
end as daynumber
```

Similarly, you could write another case statement to evaluate the weeknumber though it would be more complex than this.

Comment: Thank you for your response Pandey, I am able to generate daynumbers but now trying to get weeknumbers accordingly.